# Problem with list activity

Tags: android, list, android-activity

I have implmented pagination and it display 5 records per page. Now suppose I am on page 3 and click 3'rd element then 3'rd element of page-1 is selected.

I am not able to figure out problem as I always create new list object while setting data.

I used below code

```
temp = new ArrayList();
this.someListAdapter = new SomeListAdapter(this, R.layout.row_facet,temp);
setListAdapter(this.someListAdapter );
```

Below is signature of SomeListAdapter class.

```
public class SomeListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VoNeighborhood> {
}
```

Please help....

Comment: What do you mean with "always create new list object". From looking at your code it seems that your current Activity is your ListView (= list object). You should provide more code for us to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

There really aren't enough details here about how you do pagination with your `ListView`.

So I might guess you're overriding `onListItemClick` and using the `position` variable it sends you, but you then don't take into account the page you're on?

Alternatively, just don't use pagination as you have an infinite canvas to scroll your list within — I don't think I've recall seeing an Android app so far that uses pagination!